# How should i sort out versioning and offline testing on a website

Tags: php, git, apache, svn

I am an avid webdev hobbyist and freelance, up until now I simply edit the website live (put a maintenance message up while its being made),  now all my projects up until now have also been very small.

eg I make a site, show em, take money and go, I've never had to work on a site after it's gone live.

Now my new project is pretty big and I know I will have to edit it after its gone live and maybe have a small team of devs (atm just me)

So how do people professionally handle this? I know I will need a prefix-amp app cos i run an apache server, I've also heared that people use github for versioning, but I'm not really sure because apparently its not svn?

Thanks

ps. I have a windows 7 pc, so no mac apps please

Comment: its a joke that all the local webserver emulator things are prefix-amp, like lamp, wamp, xamp etc

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. And I pray that you will not use one of those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> up until now i simply edit the website live

Terrible in my book ;)

> so how do people professionally handle this?

First you need to setup a development server (it would be best to keep it as close as possible to the expected live environments). On this server you would install all the software you need.

You may also want to setup a staging server.

> i know i will need a prefix-amp app

I hope you are not talking about those one click installers. If you would do it professionally you should install everything yourself that way you can set it up the way you need it.

> ive also heared that people use github for versioning, but im not really sure because apparently its not svn?

GitHub is just a website. What you are looking for is git or svn for versioning. You could also setup a git or svn server locally instead of using services like GitHub. Basically what versioning is is that when somebody makes a change to the code he/she would need commit the changes. This way it is easy to keep track of changes in the codebase (like what was changed, when was it changed and by whom).

Comment: Bitbucket offers free git hosting that's private O:

Comment: i assume the development server cant be reached externally?

Comment: buying a second server for testing streches funds, is it wise to host the development site on the same site as the live one,  but make it ip/password restrictive?

Comment: sorry on phone and editing bugs out, i meant to say same server not site

Comment: I would use separate servers for development and live. When development goes down it is annoying, but when the live server goes down (for whatever reason) you have a problem that needs to be fixed yesterday. By separating both environments the cannot influence eachother.

Comment: And today there are really cheap options, like vps's and cloud servers

Comment: For my private stuff I use an old netbook for test/stage ;) Not powerful and such, but it works. Can't be that hard to find old hardware. "development" is completely on my local machine, either directly, or within a VM. All that network access costs to much time during dev. // Oh, and update: On Amazons EC2-platform a micro (beside some other things) is free for one year.

Answer (score 3):

- Local XAMP-stack (LAMP, or WAMP) for development
- intranet-system for test and maybe staging
- Of course the live system
- Versioncontrol, I prefer `git`. Of course you can use SVN too, but... lets say: It's SVN.
- Make changes local, test this changes local
- everythings fine: Push it into the "master" vcs-repository
- New version ready (or it's "sunday-night-release-time")? Push all that stuff on test/stage
- Everythings fine there too: Push it into the live system

Thats very shortened of course, but it should give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

The tool where you manage your software version is not that important. Use Git, or SVN or whatever, the one you like most. But *use* _one_.

Equally important is that you run the "page" on two sites, a test and a live system, strictly apart. Both systems have to be very close in their layout, all changes must first be done in the test system, be verified and then done in the same manner in the live system. Do not allow changes only to be made to the live system ('cause it's just a small change'). No exceptions.

Then think about deployment: how will you transfer changed files to the target system ? You need routines for this, that run once started and don't forget a step in between.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need some kind of versioning system: either SVN or Git. GitHub is simply an online service that provides managed Git repositories. Secondly you need a development server.

If it were just you doing development, you could host both of these on your local desktop PC, but since other developers are going to be joining, you need a remote server. If you don't want to be running a server out of your home, the best option is a VPS (virtual private server) on which you can install Git, Apache, etc. and anything else you need.

As for development software, take your pick- there are loads of options. A common choice is the NetBeans IDE and TortoiseGit combo. You use NetBeans to develop your code on, automatically uploading to your development server, then you TortoiseGit to commit and sync changes.

Only when you're ready to go live do you copy the code from the dev server to the production server.

Comment: So, if i use GitHub i dont need to store any git information on my server, is that correct?

Comment: If you used GitHub, you wouldn't need to install Git yourself- you'd just need a development server running Apache, PHP, MySQL, etc.